# Warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 2)?

Tags: c, pointers, char, printf

I get the error: warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 2)

with this line: `printf("%s \n", *(group_list->name));`

I don't understand why this is a problem considering that **name** is a pointer to a char. Is it a problem with using **s**? Do I have to use a different specifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
printf("%s \n", group_list->name);
```

`s` conversion specifier expects a `char *` not a `char`.

Comment: I did use that but I don't get the output correctly. I just get for some reason this shown as output: s

Comment: @shh in that case your `group_list->name` string is not properly initialized. See the part of code that writes to the `group_list->name` string.

Comment: This is what I do: newgroup->name = (char *) group_name;                   is that incorrect? group_name comes as a argument which is const char

Comment: @shn Why the cast? What is the type of `group_name`? If it is `char *`, no problem check where `group_name` is written to.

Comment: group_name is const char, hence the cast.

Comment: @shn so `name` member should be declared as `const char *` not `char *`.

Comment: do you mean do this: (const char *) newgroup->name = group_name; Or do you mean change the definition of name?

Comment: No, I mean change the type declaration of `name` member in the structure declaration.

Comment: Yep tried that just now. Still get s as an output. Very strange.